# Returning an integer value from a function declared void

Tags: c

The following program compiles with no error (only warnings) on some compilers. But can we predict its output? If so, how?

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    printf("%d",fun(5));
}

void fun(int i)
{
    if(i%2)
        return i;
    else
        return i+2;
}
```

Comment: This code won't run!

Comment: The compiler [goes crazy](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe2811035947df15) over this code.

Comment: it won't compile. just copy-and-paste, then click the run!

Comment: You can ask the compiler to predict the output of this question (if that can even be called a question), and see if he (or she) knows the answer...

Comment: @chris not without haranguing you about these horrors and threatening you to fork bomb if you don't stop immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this *can* compile. No, it *can't* be executed safely.

Since you didn't declare `fun` above its use in `main`, it is defaulted to an `int` return type, and any number of arguments. It's as if the compiler added :

```
int fun(); // Implicit declaration for the function used below

void main()
{
        printf("%d",fun(5));
}
```

When the compiler then encounters your definition, it will warn about mismatched declaration and definition, based on this implicit declaration.

It will then warn you again about you returning a value from a function you just declared `void`.

Note that it won't warn you about the use of the return value of a `void` function, because when it's wiring up the `fun` call in your printf, it still has only the implicit declaration of `fun`.

You'll get some more warning about the return type of `main` which must be `int`. And then the compilation ends "successfully".

But all the problems above are a source of Undefined Behaviour. You shouldn't have done that, and the compiler was kind enough to warn you (it isn't mandated to do so). If you execute the resulting executable, it can literally do anything.

I tried it and it printed "1". Maybe yours will print "5". It could have printed "potato", or make my socks catch on fire as far as the standard is concerned.

The bottom line is : no, we can't predict output or behaviour for a program that has UB.

**Edit:** I shouldn't write that I shouldn't write that I shouldn't write that...

So you get 0 or 1. What's most probably happening :

- Your function gets wired as if it returned an integer, according to the implicit declaration.
- Inside your function, your program computes the 2-modulus of the number, and stores the result in a register.
- You then try to return a value. But the compiler knows that `void` functions don't return anything. So it ignores what you have written after `return`.
- Execution comes back from your function. As said above, your function is wired as returning an `int`, so the calling code fetches what it "believes" is your return value. And it happens that an `int`-returing function's return value is to be stored in the register that was used earlier. So, the calling code gets the value of the modulus.

Your question is being treated harshly, because the compiler screamed at you all along that you were writing nonsense.

But it's interesting nonetheless, because often UB is not warned about by the compiler, and can lead to unpredictable and hard-to-track bugs. Knowing their possible sources can help you. But never rely on what you discover during these experiments.

Comment: actually .. when i try to print.. its also printing 1. I have tried a lot of times... and 

when an even no is passed is returns 0 and whenever an odd no is passed it returns 1........ It is just a mere coincidence or there is some logic behind this??

I have tried with many numbers..

Comment: thanks Quentin... completely understood the concept..